# ASUS X409FA battery light states

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard, battery, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS X409FA Laptop, a little over a year old (out of warranty) and it suddenly won't switch on. It exhibits the following symptoms:

a) Display doesn't come on at all (not even to show BIOS startup).
b) Power light comes on.
c) Battery light flashes white three times over 5 seconds (one flash each second with a one second gap in between), then the battery light goes off, then repeats the three flashes cycle.
d) The keyboard lights operate (CAPS LOCK).
e) The internal fan comes on.

No matter what I've tried, this PC STILL will not do anything. I've tried replacing RAM, to no avail. I've tried downloading the latest BIOS and putting it onto a USB flash drive, but the laptop still won't display or do anything.

I'm thinking that the three flashes is a code for something, but I cannot find what. I've tried ASUS' site and various other places, but to no avail.

*EDIT: 11 Dec 2020 - All I'd like to know is if anyone understand what this flashing cycle actually means? I'm not looking for how to fix it (although the two may be linked). Thanks!*

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Tony.